# arrow function not working in react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote some react JS code here:

```
import React from "react"

    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                count: 0
            };
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        }

        handleClick(prevState){
            this.setState(prevState => {count: prevState.count +1});
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Increment</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

This crushed the entire program. Here, arrow function has only one statement, So I removed the brackets and the return keyword, even if I add `return` keyword, it won't work either.

```
handleClick(prevState){
    this.setState(prevState => return {count: prevState.count +1});
}
```

what is happening? What am I missing, thank you

Comment: Remove the `return` keyword and put the object in `()`. `this.setState(prevState => ({count: prevState.count +1}));`

Comment: One line arrow functions have their return statement implicit. You're returning twice `this.setState(prevState => ({count: prevState.count +1}))`

Comment: Instead of "describing" the error with _"crushed the entire program"_ you should add any error messages from the browser (and there will definitely be one)

Comment: Everyone's given you the answer already, but just a bit of context: when you have an arrow function followed by brackets, `(prevState) => {}`, it runs whatever is in the brackets as if it's a normal code block in a normal function, so you've basically written `function(){count: prevState.count +1}`, which doesn't make sense (and I think it's probably a syntax error). On the other hand, an arrow function followed by, for example, a number or string or variable, or by parenthases, with no brackets, directly returns that value, or whatever is inside the parenthases.

Comment: thank you @TKoL, just I didn't understand the last sentence. you are saying if arrow functions are followed by `()` directly returns the value. Thank you

Comment: @BasirPayenda https://jsfiddle.net/3b1emc7q/ -- made this to illustrate

Comment: But yes, the general format of function `const x = () => (n);`, where you're assigning the arrow function to `x` and `n` is basically anything, whether it be a variable, a number, an object, whatever -- later on, when you call the function `x()`, it will return `n`

Comment: Thank you so much, you have a kind spirit

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use prevState, this should solve your problem:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  handleClick = () => {
   this.setState({
       count: this.state.count + 1  
   })
};


  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>{count}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.state.count)}>Increment</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you are missing extra brackets:

```
handleClick(prevState){
    this.setState(prevState => {
          return {count: prevState.count +1}
    });
}
```

or wrap the body in brackets.

```
handleClick(prevState){
    this.setState(prevState => ({count: prevState.count +1}) );
}
```

Arrow statements confused me for a while, until I started to read them like this, with progressively simpler syntax.

```
prevState = function(){}
prevState = () => { }
prevState => { }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate further, I am almost new in JS. Why do I have to wrap that with `{}` and use return afterward? there is no need for `return` if there is only one statement

Comment: The alternative to this is to wrap the single statement in brackets. e.g. count => ({ count: prevState.count +1 });  JS thinks your brackets in this instance denote the function body, when they actually denote the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code fixed:

```js
import React from 'react'

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  }

  handleClick = () => this.setState(({ count }) => ({ count: count + 1 }))

  render() {
    const { count } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{count}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

the bug/error:

```js
this.setState(prevState => {count: prevState.count +1});
```

the fix:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }))
```